# To which Schengen country should I apply for a visa?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm an Indian student. I'll be visiting Germany for a conference from 1-4 July as well as the Netherlands (30th June). To which country should I apply for a visa? A university in the Netherlands is providing roundtrip airfare and I have accommodation and food covered by the universities in both Germany and the Netherlands.

I was thinking of applying for a German visa so that I can get it faster, in comparison to the Netherlands. This is the first time I'm travelling outside I of India, and have no idea about how long it takes for the visa process. I have a valid B1 US visa to visit there at end of July.

Netherland's University is providing me roundtrip travel fare and I have accommodation, food covered by the respective universities.

Do I even have to mention the Netherlands visit when applying for a German visa?

Comment: Full itinerary needed to answer

Comment: Is the conference in Germany somehow connected with the Netherland's University? Or you visit that conference on your own?

Comment: No connection between both. Travel for German university conference is on me. So what should I do? Should I state that I'm going to Netherlands and show that or should I apply for Netherlands but in that case, i'll be spending more time in Germany?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a tricky one. As it appears you already know you must apply to the country that's the *main destination* of your trip. Finding out what that is is the problem here.

Going just by the itinerary you have sketched it would sound like Germany is your main destination -- it's both where you spend most of the time *and* where the conference is.

However, you also mention that a university in the Netherlands is *paying* for your travels -- for some reason we don't know, but it must be pretty important, which strongly suggests that the Netherlands is your actual main destination.

If you apply to Germany, they're going to be confused why the Dutch university is paying for your tickets (since you must disclose in the application how the trip is funded).

On the other hand, if you apply to the Netherlands, being funded by the Dutch university is a strong reason why that actually is the main destination of the trip, so they *should* not have any reason to think you're consulate shopping (which is the main reason for getting into trouble in these cases).

Personally I would pick the Netherlands, but a case could also be made for Germany. Arguably the most important thing right now is that you *pick one* and get an application in as soon as humanly possible -- you're somewhat late already, but not so late as to be hopeless.

And yes, no matter where you apply, you must provide an itinerary and documentation for your *entire visit* to the Schengen area, not just for the part of it in the country whose consulate you're applying to.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that there's a pretty good case for Germany as the main destination (the conference, all but one day of the trip is there), but the key thing we don't know is why the OP is going to the Netherlands on the 30th and whether what they plan to do there really makes it the main destination. Since there's so little time left, it would be a real shame to waste several days submitting an application to the wrong consulate to have it returned with a recommendation to submit it to the other one.

Comment: @ZachLipton: We do know the OP's mystery errand in the Netherlands is important enough for an organization located there to pay for his airfare. In the visa application, the OP should obviously be a lot more forthcoming than he is with us about what that errand is. (And it would be even more of a shame to waste the same several days on waffling over where to apply, ending up too late for _either_ of the options -- an application that is not filed at all cannot possibly be successful).

Comment: Yes, that's the Dilemma? I'm now considering to apply Netherland (tomorrow appointment). Please guide me in case you defer of think otherwise.

Comment: I really think Nederlands.  You **go their first** and that's the end of it.  Also that they are paying makes it a knock-down case.